# Spark Streaming - Error when reading from Kinesis

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm new with Apache Spark Streaming. Trying to build Spark to read value from Kinesis Stream. This is my python script

```
import settings
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kinesis import KinesisUtils,   InitialPositionInStream
spark_context = SparkContext(master="local[2]", appName=settings.KINESIS_APP_NAME)

streaming_context = StreamingContext(sparkContext=spark_context, batchDuration=settings.BATCH_DURATION)

kinesis_good_stream = KinesisUtils.createStream(
ssc=streaming_context, kinesisAppName=settings.KINESIS_APP_NAME,
streamName=settings.KINESIS_GOOD_STREAM, endpointUrl=settings.KINESIS_ENDPOINT,
awsAccessKeyId=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, awsSecretKey=settings.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
checkpointInterval=settings.KINESIS_CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL, regionName=settings.KINESIS_REGION,
initialPositionInStream=InitialPositionInStream.LATEST)

counts = kinesis_good_stream.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
    .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
counts.pprint()

streaming_context.start()
streaming_context.awaitTermination()
```

The settings file

```
# Kinesis Configuration
KINESIS_REGION = 'ap-southeast-1'
KINESIS_ENDPOINT = 'kinesis.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
KINESIS_GOOD_STREAM = 'GoodStream'
KINESIS_BAD_STREAM = 'BadStream'
KINESIS_CHECKPOINT_INTERVAL = 2000
KINESIS_APP_NAME = 'test-spark'

# Spark context
BATCH_DURATION = 2

# AWS Credential
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_SECRET_KEY = ''
```

I run the script with this command

```
spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly.jar kinesis.py
```

From my django project

```
INFO:snowplow_tracker.emitters:GET request finished with status code: 200
INFO:snowplow_tracker.emitters:POST request finished with status code: 200
```

From my collector, noticed that writing to Kinesis is successful

```
08:00:19.720 [pool-1-thread-9] INFO  c.s.s.c.s.sinks.KinesisSink - Successfully wrote 2 out of 2 records
```

For my Spark Streaming

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-11-25 07:59:25
-------------------------------------------

16/11/25 07:59:30 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 345.0 (TID 173)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(Lorg/apache/spark/storage/BlockId;)Lscala/Option;
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisBackedBlockRDD.getBlockFromBlockManager$1(KinesisBackedBlockRDD.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisBackedBlockRDD.compute(KinesisBackedBlockRDD.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:390)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

For my Kinesis Stream, I'm using 1 Shard and set Spark Context with 2 Cores

Comment: Can you post your sbt / maven build file so we can see what versions you are on? Particularly the aws library and spark versions

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you're using pyspark, my bad

Comment: I'm using pyspark from Spark 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the error. I'm running with Spark-2.0.2 but I'm using streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly.2.10-2.0.0.jar which cause the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.