# Error when running spark kinesis streaming app in cluster mode (Amazon EMR)

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I am having some serious trouble trying to run a spark kinesis streaming app into an Amazon EMR cluster (1 master, 3 workers).

What I am trying to achieve is to build a FAT jar using the sbt assembly plugin in order to run a spark-submit command on the master node. The command I am using is the following:

> spark-submit --class MyClass --master yarn --deploy-mode
>   cluster --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 2
>   hdfs://url:port/my.jar

This application, receives incoming data from a kinesis stream and based on it, executes a request (post-back) to an url I can keep track on. I have tested my app locally by running it setting Master on SparkConfig to local[cores].

Moreover here is my code and my build sbt. My project is using scala 2.11.8 and sbt 0.13.8

**build.sbt**

```
name := "my-app"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.11" % "2.0.0",
  "org.scalaj" % "scalaj-http_2.11" % "2.3.0"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

**MyClass**

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.internal.StaticCredentialsProvider
import com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitialPositionInStream
import com.keynetic_digital.model.RawKDLog
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Duration, Milliseconds, StreamingContext}
import utils.HttpRequest

/**
  * Created by franco on 18/01/17.
  */
object MyClass {

  val awsAccessKeyId : String = "xxxxxxxxx"
  val awsSecretKey : String = "xxxxxxxx"
  val kinesisStreamName : String = "xxxxxxxx"
  val kinesisEndpoint : String = "https://kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
  val appName : String = "xxxxxxxxx"


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //Set up Amazon Kinesis Client
    val kinesisClient : AmazonKinesisClient = createKinesisClient

    //Get all Kinesis shards
    val shards = kinesisClient.describeStream(kinesisStreamName).getStreamDescription.getShards.size()

    val batchInterval = Milliseconds(5000)

    // Create Spark Streaming Context
    val ssc : StreamingContext = createContext(batchInterval)
    val regionName = RegionUtils.getRegionByEndpoint(kinesisEndpoint).getName

    // Create the Kinesis DStreams
    val kinesisStreams = (0 until shards).map { i =>
      KinesisUtils.createStream(ssc, appName,
        kinesisStreamName,kinesisEndpoint,
        regionName,InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, batchInterval * 2,
        StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
    }

    //Unified all Streams
    val stream = ssc.union(kinesisStreams)

    //Get an RDD of Option(KDLog) items
    val jsons = stream.map(bytes => Option(RawKDLog.fromJson(bytes))).filter(_.isDefined)

    jsons.foreachRDD{rdd =>
      rdd.foreach{log =>
        handleLog(log)
      }
    }

    // Start the streaming context and await termination
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

  def createKinesisClient : AmazonKinesisClient = {
    //Set System Properties for Worker
    System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", awsAccessKeyId)
    System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", awsSecretKey)

    //Setting AWS Credentials
    val credentials : BasicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId,awsSecretKey)

    //Setting AWS Credential Provider
    val provider : StaticCredentialsProvider = new StaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)

    //Setting Kinesis Client
    val kinesisClient : AmazonKinesisClient = new AmazonKinesisClient(provider)
    kinesisClient.setEndpoint(kinesisEndpoint)

    kinesisClient
  }

  def createContext(batchInterval : Duration) : StreamingContext = {

    // Create Spark Configuration
    val config = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)

    // Create Spark Streaming Context
    new StreamingContext(config, batchInterval)
  }

  def handleLog(log : Option[RawKDLog]) : Unit = {
    if(log.isDefined){
      postBack(log.get)
    }
  }

  /**
    * Method that handles url postback requests
    */
  private def postBack(log : RawKDLog) = {
    //TODO url queryString replacement & request masking
    val postBackUrl : String = "url where I can track requests by tailing Nginx log"

    HttpRequest(postBackUrl) .asString

  }

}
```

After submiting the application in the cluster Master node, the following error happends.

```
17/01/18 14:39:26 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 74, ip-172-31-42-151.us-west-2.compute.internal): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(Lorg/apache/spark/storage/BlockId;)Lscala/Option;
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisBackedBlockRDD.getBlockFromBlockManager$1(KinesisBackedBlockRDD.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisBackedBlockRDD.compute(KinesisBackedBlockRDD.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
     ApplicationMaster host: 175.31.43.46
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     start time: 1484750075922
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://ip-175-31-46-219.us-west-2.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1484568737877_0012/
     user: hadoop
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1484568737877_0012 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1132)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1178)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/01/18 14:39:26 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

I would really appreciate any guidance on this subject since I am quite new to developing and working with spark apps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was stated on this question [Spark Streaming - Error when reading from Kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800457/spark-streaming-error-when-reading-from-kinesis)

Actually what happened was that I had set up my cluster with amazon emr 5.2.1 which uses Spark 2.0.2 and I bundled my FAT jar to use **spark-streaming-kinesis-asl-assembly_2.11** 2.0.0.

Therefore my application couldn't read input data from Kinesis

I switched to emr 5.0.0 which is the latest version using Spark 2.0.0 and everything executed as expected